# Can't get a map to display on Android 2.3

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator

The following code works nicely on the iPhone simulator but, on Android 2.3, I just get a blank map with the Google logo on it (see attached screenshot).

```
var mainWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:'#fff', fullscreen:true, navBarHidden: true})
mainWin.open();

var win = mainWin;

var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    region:{latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993, latitudeDelta:0.5, longitudeDelta:0.5},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true
});

win.add(mapview);
```

Any idea what's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the SDK you get this when you are [missing the maps api key](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/android-maps). You could try looking into that.

Also are you using the android emulator? Because if you are, you need to verify that your images has the google apis.